# Is there a proper way to call git clean in jenkins pipeline groovy script?

Tags: git, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I do not want to use `checkout scm`, that's the reason why I ask.
I want to checkout multiple repositories in the jenkinsfile and make sure that the workspace is clean (git clean)

For `checkout scm` there's a checkbox to do exactly that. How can I reproduce this for the git checkout function in groovy? All i've found regarding this topic is to call `git clean -fdx`via shell call, but I'd prefer a clean solution in groovy over a shell call, if that's possible.

```
  def checkoutGit(def cred,def repo, def branch)
  {
    git credentialsId: cred, url: repo, branch: branch
  }
```

Something like described here:
https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/226122247-How-to-customize-Checkout-for-Pipeline-Multibranch

```
node {
    checkout([
        $class: 'GitSCM',
        branches: scm.branches,
        extensions: scm.extensions + [[$class: 'CleanCheckout']],
        userRemoteConfigs: scm.userRemoteConfigs
    ])
      
    //Build, Test, Stage, Deploy
    [...]
}
```

but not for checkout but for the git function. (see the example above)

Comment: The `git` step method functionality is really a subset of the `GitSCM` class. If you cannot achieve this with the class: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-scm-step/, then you would not be able to do it with the step method: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/git/. The docs confirm you cannot do this with the step method.

Comment: Thank you, i feared that already. can you please answer the question so i an mark it as solved? @MattSchuchard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [git step method](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/git/) functionality is a subset of the [GitSCM](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-scm-step/) class specified as an argument within the `workflow-scm-step` plugin `checkout` method. If you cannot achieve the functionality with the class, then it would also not be possible within the step method.

In this situation, the documentation for the step method confirms that a clean is not possible. As mentioned in the question, the clean is only possible within the `checkout` if you want to make use of the Groovy bindings to Git. Therefore, in your situation you would indeed have to use `git clean -fdx` within the shell step method for the desired functionality.